# take time between two inputs c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Im having tropel with a little project of mine and would like some help.
this is the code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(timetaker) 
{

}

int after()
{
    srand(data from above);

    for (int x = 1; x<2;x++)
    {
      cout << 1+(rand()) << endl;
    }
}
```

what im having trople with is the function that takes time and gives it to the int after() function. But i would be gratefull for some help with the int main (timetaker)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "First Click: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        unsigned int start = clock();
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Next when you are ready ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Time taken in millisecs: " << clock() << endl;
        std::cout << "Now for the random number. Are you ready" << endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        srand(clock());

        for (int x = 1; x<2;x++)
        {
          cout << 1+(rand()) << endl;
        }
        std::cout << "That is the random number from the time taken.";
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you put the code you want to call before the place you want to call it from.  Getting a time value for `srand()`, and passing it from `main()`, can be done as illustrated below...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void after(time_t seed)
{
    srand(seed);

    for (int x = 1; x<2;x++)
    {
      cout << 1+(rand()) << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    do_stuff(time(NULL));
}
```

Comment: I will check into the reply thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Considering the very vague nature of this question, I'd say this is your best resource:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/

Comment: I will see that link thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any question. By the way, you're missing the return value for `main` and `after`. Also you can't do `int main (timetaker)` what should that be ?

Your srand function should work with data from the `main` function ? You will need to pass some parameters in your function `int after`.

I also would not recommend using `using namespace std;` as this may cause undefined behavior if you're going to implement, for instance, your own cout function. Using `std::` is the better way. Still, it's your choice, and in this code it's fine.

*If you want to work with time, you may check out those links:*

[**Time**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/)

[**Clock**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/)

Comment: I will thx for the fast reply